# Is this intuitive by graph ? Or its needs rigorous proof

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A double differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f(x)f^{\prime \prime}(x) \ne 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Can we conclude $f(x)f^{\prime \prime}(x) >0$ for all $\mathbb{R}$ , even though continuity of $f''(x)$ is not given. I thought of making a contradiction by graph supposing $f(x)>0$ and $f''(x) <0$ , I thought graph would need to cut x axis hence after that $f(x)<0$ ( contradiction) but I don't have a good calculus based proof on this fact. As continuity of $f''(x)$ not given is also a problem for all $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Domain problem in yours in all f(x) ,f'(x),f"(x) @Anas Khaled

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: It seems like if $f''$ ever jumps over the horizonal axis to change signs, this would create a badly behaved point where $f'$ can no longer be differentiated (not allowed). If so, this means $f''$ is always positive or always negative. $f$ always positive or negative and the behavior of convex and concave functions then limits your choices. I think it's true that $f\cdot f''$ > 0...

Comment: @Ben Yeah Sir i got that thing from just observing the graph :)

Comment: @Ben sir does following IVT implies continuity ?

Comment: @WayBig: No. IVT does not imply continuity.

Comment: @WayBig: For example: consider derivative of the function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=x^2\sin \frac 1x$, when $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Nice example @Koro , is there a proof by contradiction for this fact ig for a function f(x) , our just counter example is the only proof?

Comment: That example is the proof by contradiction in a way. Consider the statement: "If a function satisfies IVT on the closed interval $[a,b]$, then it is continuous." If this statement were true, every function following IVT would be continuous but $f'(x):\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ (as defined in previous comment) clearly violates the statement on any interval $[-t,t]$, where $t\gt 0$. Hence the statement is false.

Comment: Understood Sir ty again :)

Comment: @WayBig: Great :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(x)f''(x)\ne 0$, it follows that for all real $x, f''(x)\gt 0$ or $f''(x)\lt 0$ for all real $x$.

Because if there exist $x_1,x_2$ such that $f''(x_1)\gt 0$ and $f''(x_2)\lt 0$ then by Darboux theorem, there exists $c\in (x_1, x_2)$ such that $f''(c)=0$, which is a contradiction. (Why? Refer **Note**)

Similarly $f(x)\gt 0$ for all real $x$ or $f(x)\lt 0$ for all real $x$.

WLOG suppose that $f"(x)\gt 0$ for all $x$ and $f(x)\lt 0$ for all $x$, it follows that $f(x)f"(x)\lt 0$ for all $x$.  There exist $x'$ such that $f'(x')\ne 0$.

**Case 1:** $f'(x')\lt 0$ 
By LMVT,
For $x\lt x', f'(x)\lt f'(x')$ 
So for $x\lt x', f(x)-f(x')\gt xf'(x')\implies f(x)\gt f(x')+xf'(x')\implies f(x)$ will be positive when $x$ is negative enough. This will contradict our assumption that $f(x)\lt 0$

**Case 2:** $f'(x')\gt 0$ 
Can you take it from here?

**Note:** Define $g(x)=f'(x)$. Since $g$ is continuous on $[x_1,x_2]$, it must attain maximum on the interval.Let $c\in [x_1,x_2]$ be the point where maximum is attained. If $c=x_1$, then $g'(c)=f''(x_1)=\lim_{x\to x_1^+}\frac {f'(x)-f'(x_1)}{x-x_1}\le 0$, contradiction (Note that since $f'(x_1)$ is maximum, Numerator is not positive) and similarly $c\ne x_2$. So $c\in (x_1,x_2)$. Since $c$ is a point of extrema of $g$ on $[x_1,x_2]$, we must have $g'(c)=f''(c)=0$.

Comment: Ty i got the point , just one thing Sir how do we prove that f"(x) is fully continuous over all R ?

Comment: @WayBig: $f"$ does not have to be continuous. $f"(x)$ however, being a derivative of $f'(x)$ satisfies Intermediate Value property and that is due to Darboux theorem.

Comment: @WayBig: Please see the revised answer for more details.

Comment: One thing Sir , if we r saying "assuming f"(x) <0 for all x" doesnt that imply itself we r taking it to be continuous ?

Comment: Dont we need to apply darboux in a interval not for all x isnt? ( Just asking from the first statement u wrote )

Comment: @WayBig: Either $f''(x)\gt 0$ for all real $x$ or $f''(x)\lt 0$ for all real $x$ actually follows from the fact that $f''(x)$ is non zero on $\mathbb R$. And it does not imply continuity of $f''(x)$. Refer note in the revised answer above. There is no mention of continuity of $f''$. My first statement in answer simply claims that $f''$ doesn't change sign on $\mathbb R$ and subsequently it is proven using the arguments in "note" or if you know Darboux theorem, you may directly conclude that there will be some $c$ in the interval $(x_1,x_2)$ where $f''$ becomes $0$.

Comment: Sir now i got it perfectly  by your method ty , can u check that proof by contradiction in the comment below my question too ?

Comment: Per the note: if $g$ attains its maximum on the interval at an endpoint, it's not necessarily true that $g' =0$ at that endpoint. But if $g'$ has opposite signs at the endpoints, this means $g$ must have a local min or max somewhere inside the interval, and at that point, $g' =0$

Comment: @Ben: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I have revised the argument.

Comment: @WayBig: Please note the revision in "note" in the answer.

Comment: Ty for the correction @Ben Sir , yes i now saw it Koro Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

As you observe that $f(x)$ and $f^{\prime \prime }(x)$ can't change sign as the derivative has the [darboux property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) Now we can assume that $f(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $ as if it was $<0$ we can apply it to $-f$.
For the sake of contradiction assume $f^{\prime \prime}(x) < 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $

Consider $c = f^{\prime}(0)$ if $c =0$ then $\exists \alpha>0$ such that $f^{\prime}(\alpha) < 0$(WHy?)

Or $f(x) - f(\alpha) < f^{\prime}(\alpha) (x- \alpha) \ \forall x > \alpha$ And take $x \to \infty$ to contradict that $f(x) >0$

If $c >0$ then $f(0) - f(x)>-f^{\prime}(0)x \ \forall x <0$ again take $x \to - \infty$ and contradict that $f(x) >0$

Now I think you can proceed

Comment: Nice. I forgot about Darboux.

Comment: @Aditya Dwivedi That "why" is bc the f'(x) is strictly decreasing so value at a >0 must be less than what value is at 0 right ? And can u share a proof of darboux IVT thing ?

Comment: IMO this is the best answer.

Comment: Well i liked both , so couldnt make which is best , @Koro Sir what u think ?

Comment: @WayBig: I don't know which one is better of the two answers. It's really up to you, which answer makes you understand the concepts etc. I posted my answer including lot of details with the idea that many can understand. 

Comment: @Koro I agree with you, maybe he liked my approach because he thought in the same line like this

Comment: Exactly @Aditya Dwivedi

Comment: Yes, sorry, not trying to stir up trouble! Anyway, neat problem with a cool result.